# How to prevent WebStorm 11 to launch browser when using gulp in terminal

Tags: windows, browser, webstorm

When I type `C:\wamp\www\>gulp` in the terminal in WebStorm 11 my default Windows 7 browser is auto launch.

I tried changing the default settings in WebStorm but is not working, take a look:

[image]

What else can I try? any idea?

Comment: And what page it opens? What your gulp tasks do? Maybe one of the tasks launches it?

Comment: @LazyOne where can I check on my gulp file that? do you think is this one? gulp.task('build:index', function () {
        return gulp.src('./build/index.html')
            .pipe(inject(gulp.src(config.build_src), {ignorePath: 'build'}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dev));
    })

Comment: Yes -- file with such content. Check it -- maybe one of the tasks launches the browser (e.g. task that launches dev server)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking for an answer. On my case, the problem wasn't webstorm but gulp. Here is the gulp task I'm using. I added "open: false".

```
gulp.task('serve', function () {
        browserSync({
            server: {
                baseDir: config.dev
            },
            open: false
        });
    });
```